# Vuex: store object not visible in components

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

When I try to access the vuex store inside a random component, undefined is returned. However,  I injected the store into my Vue object. Does anyone know how to solve this? I could import the store object into every component manually, but that's not really clean...
My files look like this:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

import routes from './config/routes'
import locales from './lang/locales'
import store from './store'

//Routing support
Vue.use(VueRouter);
//Backend support
Vue.use(VueResource);
//Language support
Vue.use(VueI18n);


Vue.config.lang = 'nl';

Object.keys(locales).forEach(function (lang) {
    Vue.locale(lang, locales[lang])
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    store,
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/app/',
    routes: routes
});

new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import fleet from './modules/fleet'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        fleet
    }
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    import NavBar from './assets/navBar.vue'
    export default {
        created() {
            console.log(this.$store)
        },
        components: {
            NavBar
        }
    }
</script>
```

`this.$store` returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const router = new VueRouter({
>       store,
>       mode: 'history',
>       base: '/app/',
>       routes: routes });
>
> new Vue({
>       router }).$mount('#app');

Store is designed to be set up in `new Vue`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

You've placed it into VueRouter instance instead.

Proper code combined:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
  base: ...
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Omg sorry, I didn't notice this at all... Thank you